# Rating System with Stars. Save rate in DB

Tags: javascript, database, symfony, rating, rate

I created a sort of blog, and I have, for example, articles.
In every article I implemented a star rating plugin that works graphically.

This is the screenshot of the view:

[image]

To make it works i used the jRate plugin, and i added in the page this JavaScript block:

```
    {% block javascripts %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var that = this;
            var toolitup = $("#jRate").jRate({
                minSelected: 0,
                                maxSelected: 5,
                                readOnly: false,
                                shape: 'STAR',
                                width: 30,
                                height: 30,
                                precision: 1,

                onChange: function(rating) {
                    $('#demo-onchange-value').text("Il tuo voto: "+rating);
                },
            });

});

    </script>
        {% endblock %}
```

The "+rating" variable is the rate of course. So i was thinking that I can use that variable to save it in a field of my article table in the db.
So I added a new field in the article entity that is:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="rate", type="integer",nullable=true)
 */
private $rate;
```

How can I save the rating in that field?

Comment: Create a form and link your js value to an hidden (or not) field.

Comment: Ok, but my problem is to link it

Comment: in your onChange : `$('#idOfMyField').val(rating);`, after submit your form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For star rating I have been using https://github.com/blackknight467/StarRatingBundle. If you wish to use your own implementation, at least you can look how they do it. Basically the rating field is represented by a hidden input, and when the stars selected changed , also change the value of the input. On form submition the field is saved normally as an integer. I hope this help you.

Comment: I already saw that. I used the guide to implent it, but i get errors... maybe i was doing something wrong, like where i put the bundle.. i don't know

Comment: So the problem is not "How can I save the rating in that field?", posting the errors may be help.

Comment: Attempted to load class "StarRatingBundle" from namespace "blackknight467\StarRatingBundle".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

Comment: That's weird, if you import the bundle with composer and then initialize in the AppKernel as the documentation says, that should not happen. I don't see the need of import that class in any place. In the log, in what class say that it happend?

Comment: Exactly! It's weird... The problem is in the AppKernel were i copy the string  new blackknight467\StarRatingBundle\StarRatingBundle(),

Comment: that line is for composer, you means `new blackknight467\StarRatingBundle\StarRatingBundle(),` right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98251/discussion-between-abdiel-and-kandeeholly).

Comment: Sorry to bump this question. So how to send blackknight467 into entity field? Any an example of controller for that?